# Python function definition

Tags: python

```
def CsMatrix(X not None):
```

I meet this piece of code. For ***X not None***, I haven't met this kind of syntax? So I write my test code:

```
def test(x not None):

    pass
```

However, I got SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
Can anyone explain this syntax?

Comment: It's not valid syntax...

Comment: That's not valid Python.

Comment: Where did you meet it? If it was at a bar, maybe the programmer was drunk.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `def CsMatrix(x=None)` providing `x` with a default value in the event that no value for `x` is given when the function is called?

Comment: It might help if you told us what it is that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here is the link at line 22: [link](https://github.com/ibayer/fastFM/blob/master/fastFM/ffm.pyx)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. What you can do is

```
def test(x):
    if x is None:
        return
    ... #  All the further actions with x
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid syntax neither for [python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/function.html) nor [python 3.x](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_functions.php), maybe you wanted to declare your function with a `None` default value, something like this:

```
def CsMatrix(X = None):
    if X is None:
        print("Yeah, I'm None")

CsMatrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def CsMatrix(X not None):
    pass
```

Is it possible that you mis-read it? Definitely not valid...
If you have the link to thesite where you seen it, could you post it?

You also said "For x not None" implying it might be used in a for loop as well?  This would also be bad syntax.
You can (as suggested) set a default value for "x", in this case 'None'

```
def test(x = None):
    if x is None:
        print "Nothing was passed to this function!"
    elif x not None:
        print "The function received: ", x
    else:
        print "There's no way this should ever print"
```